# Diamond pattern using while loop in c++

Tags: c++, loops, design-patterns, while-loop

I am trying to print a diamond pattern using while loop in c++ that is based on the diamond's length however i'm not getting the output i wanted to see. what seems to be the problem with my code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "Length of diamond:";
    int length = 0;
    cin >> length; 
    length = length/2;
    int r = -length;
    while (r <= length) {
        r++;
        int c = -length;
        while (c <= length) {
            c++; 
            if (abs (r) + abs (c) == length) cout << ".";
            else cout << " ";
        }
    
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Looks to me that the problem is that you increment `r` and `c` before doing your calculations not afterwards. But I'm only staring at the code, I could be wrong. In any case problems like these are easily solved by using a debugger and observing the behaviour of your program as it runs, instead of just looking at the code and trying to figure it out.

Comment: You need to change to `int r = -length-1;int c = -length-1;` because you ignored the first drawing.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882003/john) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933180/diamond-pattern-using-while-loop-in-c/63934205#comment113054111_63933180), the problem is with incrementing `r` and `c`. Here is corrected code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int length, r, c;
    cout << "Length of diamond: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << '\n';
    length /= 2;
    r = -length;
    while (r <= length) {
        c = -length;
        while (c <= length) {
            if (abs(r) + abs(c) == length)
                cout << '.';
            else
                cout << ' ';
            c++;
        }
        r++;
        cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Sample Run](https://wandbox.org/permlink/D0mHG1bweThOaCg6) :

```
Length of diamond: 9
    .    
   . .   
  .   .  
 .     . 
.       .
 .     . 
  .   .  
   . .   
    .
```

---

Note that there may be more than one way to get the desired output. (For example, making `r = -length - 1` instead of `r = -length`, same for `c`, as suggested by [Zhu Song](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13566062/zhu-song) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933180/diamond-pattern-using-while-loop-in-c/63934205#comment113054250_63933180).

Advice : Make yourself familiar with your debugger. Avoid putting `using namespace std;`.